# PHP - Cant see my image

Tags: php

Im beginner as php programmer,so ive got various problem , one of them after I made an easy upload system,when I want to see the picture which I uploaded to the server,doesnt shown.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); //the target path that the file will move
/*Moving the picture,to the server if successed the condition will be true*/
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
        echo"התמונה הועלתה בהצלחה!";
        echo"</br></br>";
        echo $target_path;
        $show_photo = "<img src='$target_path' alt='Picture' class='photo' />"; 
        function AddToAllPhotosList()
        {
        $myFile = "photosorder.php"; //ListOfAllPhotos
        $fileHander = fopen($myFile,'a') or die ("אין אפשרות לפתוח את הקובץ");

        }
    }
    else
        echo "Error.";
?>
```

The Line -`"<img src='$target_path' alt='Picture' class='photo' />"` , Doesn't shows the photo why ?

Comment: try doing an echo $show_photo and see if it is referencing the correct $target_path.

Comment: What is the value of `$target_path`? It's probably a diskpath like `C:/www/site/images/img.ext`, which needs to be converted to: `http://www.mysite.com/images/img.ext`

Comment: dsebert i forgot to add echo -_- thank you a lot really :) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$show_photo = "<img src='$target_path' alt='Picture' class='photo' />";
```

Replace To:

```
echo "<img src='$target_path' alt='Picture' class='photo' />";
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is being saved to variable $show_photo, but is not being echoed.

...
$show_photo = ""; 
**echo $show_photo;**
...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually outputting the  tags. You are currently storing them in the $show_photo variable, which is causing you problems. Either do

```
echo $show_photo;
```

after you've declared it, or replace line 10 with the following:

```
echo "<img src='$target_path' alt='Picture' class='photo' />";
```

Note - the type of quotes used are important!

Answer (score 0):

Add an echo of $show_photo which should show the html you intend to show to appear.